# Separate names for tokio worker threads and blocking threads

Tags: debugging, rust, rust-tokio

When spawning a tokio runtime, I want to give a different name to the worker threads and the blocking threads. I see that the tokio runtime builder provides a [`thread_name_fn`](https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/runtime/struct.Builder.html#method.thread_name_fn) function, but I don't know how to tell what kind of thread the current one is (worker or blocking). Are all the worker threads guaranteed to be spawned before all the blocking threads? Can I just count until I hit the number of worker threads and then switch over to naming them `blocking`?